# Continuity assumption in uniqueness of primitives (up to a constant)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, continuity

Stein and Shakarchi asks us to prove that if $f$ is continuous in an open and connected set $\Omega$ that any two primitives of $f$ differ by a constant. I don't understand why the continuity assumption is necessary. Suppose that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are both primitives of $f$ (i.e. holomorphic and $F_1' = F_2' = f$ on $\Omega$). Then $G = F_1 - F_2$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and $G' = f - f = 0$ on $\Omega$ so another theorem tells us that $G$ is constant. Thus $F_1 = F_2 + C$. So where did we use continuity?

Comment: I think the point is that Stein and Shakarchi develop the theory of line integrals only with $\textit{continuous}$ functions (as do most texts on complex analysis i think). The reason is that not all non-continuous functions are (Riemann-) integrable, so the definition of line integral might be troublesome for the non-continuous case. So in a way you use continuity for every Proposition in this chapter. (You can check that continuity is an assumption everywhere in this chapter)

Comment: @noam.szyfer Thank you that makes a lot of sense given the context.